# Counting how many numbers greater than 5 in a given array

Tags: arrays, perl

I am having an error saying that `prototype not terminated at filename.txt line number 113` where as line number 113 belongs to a different program which is running successfully.

```
sub howmany( 
    my @H = @_;
    my $m = 0;

    foreach $x (@H) {
        if ( $x > 5 ) {
            $m +=1;
        }
        else { 
            $m +=0;
        }
    }
    print "Number of elements greater than 5 is equal to: $m \n";
} 
howmany(1,6,9);
```

Comment: always start with : `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Tip: `$m += 0;`???

Comment: Tip: `howmany` should `return` the count. The `print` should be done by the caller. IO and calculations are unrelated concerns.

Comment: if the array element is greater than five, it will add one to $m otherwise it won't add anything and check the next element

Comment: That's what it should do, but you add zero instead of not adding/doing anything.

Comment: Simple solution: `sub how_many_greater_than_5 { return 0+grep { $_ > 5 } @_; } say how_many_greater_than_5(1, 6, 9);` or `sub how_many_greater_than { my $lim = shift; return 0+grep { $_ > $lim } @_; } say how_many_greater_than(5, 1, 6, 9);`

Answer (score 3):

The `sub` keyword should be followed by `{ }` not `( )` (if you define a simple function), that's why the error

```
prototype not terminated
```

After this, always start with : `use strict; use warnings;`

Put this and debug your script, there's more errors.

Last but not least, **indent your code** properly, using an editor with syntax highlighting, you will save many time debugging

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to parenthesis. 
Never do $m += 0; As you actually load processor for nothing. Of course it's not gonna be visible on such a small function, but...

```
sub howmany {
    my $m = 0;
    foreach (@_) {
        $m++ if ($_ > 5);
    }
    print "Number of elements greater than 5 is equal to: $m \n";
} 
howmany(1,6,9);
```